# Condicional en CLassName

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tailwind

Quiero agregar un condicional que dependiendo del estado muestre una clase u otra en un className pero no logro que funcione. Esto es más o menos lo que quiero hacer:

Estado:

```
const [active, changeOpcion] = useState("Dashboard");
```

Cuando el estado sea "Calendar"

```
<a href="#" className={`${active == "Calendar" ? "bg-white" : "bg-black"}`}></a>
```

Comment: probé tu código y funciona bro, si estás cambiando el estado bien? nada más te falta agregarle un = más a tu ==

Comment: El error estará en otro lado, porque eso que tienes ahí funciona. (supongo que le has agregado el dentro <a>ACA</a>)

Comment: Voy a rectificar, gracias